# What am i doing wrong in my toggle visibility

Tags: javascript, php, html

I made a html page using some simple bootstrap and have it linked to a database using some php. I want the page to be simple at the beginning, only 2 sections, and as you complete the inputs and press next, another section becomes visible. I tried doing this with a toggle visibility in javascript but for some reason it either doesn't switch between the display: none or block, doesn't take on the inputs or just simply does nothing.

Below is 2 sections, if anyone can explain why and how this does not work.

```css
/*Contect style*/

input,
textarea {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  width: 200px;
  color: #999999;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
}
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  max-width: 400px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
input:hover,
textarea:hover,
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
}
.form label {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #999999;
}
.submit input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #474E69;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
/*sections*/

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media(min-width:767px) {
  .navbar {
    padding: 20px 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .top-nav-collapse {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
.intro-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}
.about-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
  display: none;
}
.services-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.reservation-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
  display: none;
}
.contact-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<?php $servername="localhost" ; $username="root" ; $password="" ; // Create connection $conn=n ew mysqli($servername, $username, $password); // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } $conn->select_db("airports"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="contactStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="paymentFormJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <title>Licenta - Rezervare bilete de avion</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'none')
          e.style.display = 'block';
        else
          e.style.display = 'none';
      }
      //-->
  </script>
</head>



<!-- The #page-top ID is part of the scrolling feature - the data-spy and data-target are part of the built-in Bootstrap scrollspy function -->

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

  <!-- Navigation
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Home</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#reservation">Reservation</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>-->

  <!-- Intro Section -->
  <section id="intro" class="intro-section section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div style="height: 50px"></div>
          <h1>Tells us what you want!</h1>
          <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
              <h3><label for="departure">Where will you be leaving from</label></h3>
              <input class="form-control input-lg" id="departure" type="text" placeholder="Madrid, Spain" name="source">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
              <h3><label for="arrival">Where you will arrive to</label></h3>
              <input class="form-control input-lg" id="arrival" type="text" placeholder="Bucharest, Romania" name="destination">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4" style="margin-left: 33%; margin-top: 100px;">

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" name="city_search" id="aboutBtn" onclick="toggle_visibility('about')">
                <a class="page-scroll-about" href="#about" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;"> Find it </a>
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- About Section -->
  <section id="about" class="about-section">
    <div class="container" style="">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1>Pick a flight</h1>
          <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
          <form role="form">
            <?php if(isset($_GET[ "city_search"])) { $src=$ _GET[ "source"]; $dest=$ _GET[ "destination"]; $query_txt="SELECT * FROM flights WHERE source_city LIKE '%{$src}%' AND destination_city LIKE '%{$dest}%'" ; if($qu=$ conn->query($query_txt)) { while($row = $qu->fetch_row()) { echo "
            <div class=\ "form-group col-xs-12\" style=\ "border: 1px solid black; height: auto\">"; echo "
              <div class=\ " col-lg-6\" style=\ "border-right: 1px solid black; height: 100px; margin-top: 15px; font-family: arial; font-size: 32px;\">"; echo "
                <p style=\ " margin-top: 25px;\">{$row[1]}</p>"; echo "</div>"; echo "
              <div class=\ " col-lg-6\" style=\ " height: 100px; margin-top: 15px; font-family: arial; font-size: 32px;\">"; echo "
                <p style=\ " margin-top: 25px;\">{$row[2]}</p>"; echo "</div>"; echo "
              <button type=\ "submit\" class=\ "btn btn-primary btn-sm \" name=\ "flight_id\" value=\ "{$row[0]}\" id=\ "submitBtn{$row[0]}\" style=\ " margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;\" onclick=\
              "toggle_visibility('services')\"><a class=\ "page-scroll\" href=\ "#services\" style=\ "text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;\">Pick a flight</a>
              </button>"; echo "</div>"; } } } ?>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Services Section -->
  <section id="services" class="services-section section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1>Tell us about you</h1>
          <form class="form-horizontal col-lg-6" role="form" style="margin-left: 23%;">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputdefault">Name</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="John" style="text-align: center;" name="client_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputdefault">Surname</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="Doe" style="text-align: center;" name="client_surname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputdefault">ID</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="1770423112233" style="text-align: center;" name="client_id">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputdefault">Age</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="27" style="text-align: center;" name="client_age">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputdefault">Address</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="Bd. Unirii nr. 144" style="text-align: center;" name="client_address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3" style="margin-left: 80%; margin-top: 15px;">

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" name="client_flight_id" value="<?php 
                                    if(isset($_GET[" flight_id "]))
                                        echo $_GET["flight_id "];
                                    else
                                        echo "nullb ";
                                    ?>" id="reservationBtn" onclick="toggle_visibility('reservation')">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#reservation" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" onclick="toggle_visibility('reservation')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Neext </a>
              </button>

              <?php if(isset($_GET[ "client_flight_id"])) { $client_name=$ _GET[ "client_name"]; $client_surname=$ _GET[ "client_surname"]; $client_id=$ _GET[ "client_id"]; $client_age=$ _GET[ "client_age"]; $client_address=$ _GET[ "client_address"]; $client_flight_id=$
              _GET[ "client_flight_id"]; $query_txt="INSERT INTO clients (name, surname, client_id, age, address, flight_id) VALUES (\" {$client_name}\ ",\"{$client_surname}\ ", {$client_id}, {$client_age}, \"{$client_address}\
              ", {$client_flight_id})"; $conn->query($query_txt); $client_db_id = $conn->insert_id; } ?>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who answers.

Comment: Would you create jsfiddle for this, so that I can debug issue there

Comment: Because you load jQuery, toggling the visibility of an element can be done with the following statement: `$("#"+id).toggle();`

Comment: i see that you are calling toggle_visibility function with id as reservation, but I can't see any reservartion element view, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Created a JS fiddle for @ParagBhayani https://jsfiddle.net/3thpwr2h/

As for the toggle_visibility for the reservation section, it's the other half of the code i have, didn't post it all here

Comment: @Victor : Are you able to solve this issue with below answer? or you are still facing an error?

Comment: Moving the script to the bottom like Georgi Stefanov suggested makes it work sometimes. As for the jquerry approach, i'm either using it wrong or don;t understand fully how to imbed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code and moving the script in the bottom of the page seemed to fix the problem. If you are using Google Chrome always check your console (Ctrl + Shift + i) when you are messing with Javascript.
And Javascript that makes DOM manipulation should be loaded at the end of the page after all elements are loaded or using load event must in order to execute the code after the elements are loaded.

Comment: " And Javascript that makes DOM manipulation should be loaded at the end of the page after all elements are loaded." - Not necessarily. All JS code can (should) live in the head. You can handle the `load` event of the window, which wont fire until all content has been loaded. `window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);` - simply supply a function `onDocLoaded` and it will be (executed) as though the contents of that function appear as the last things in the document.

Comment: Yea and going through all this just because you want your code to be in the header? Of course, there is a way to ensure that the Javascript code will be executed at the right moment... And I wanted to provide him a simple solution to his problem.

Comment: No. Because its the most versatile method. It works both when included in JS that lives in the HTML file, and when included from external sources. It makes it explicit that the code will be run once load is complete. There's nothing stopping you from being lazy and continuing to put it at the bottom. (from: no so young web-dev)